# What diagrams should I do in each step?

Tags: uml, software-design

I want to know what kind of diagrams I should use in each step of a project lifestyle, for example in the first step I should do the use case diagram, but what diagrams should I do after this step, for example what diagrams I should use during the analyse of the project, the design, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UML diagrams priority](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26428707/uml-diagrams-priority)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to categorized the UML diagrams based on priorities/ levels?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871462/how-to-categorized-the-uml-diagrams-based-on-priorities-levels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should decide which [process model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_methodology) you want to use. Let it be Waterfall (not recommended), V-Model, Scrum, Unified Process, Rational Unified Process, etc.

Then you can start talking about first, second step and so on, because the steps depend on the process model that you use.

These diagrams you're referring to are also called artifacts, and you should only use them, if you need them and if they create value (more understanding for example), you should not use them just to have done it (only if it's an academic/school project and you want to learn).

If you want to improve your knowledge in that certain area, there are several good books out there, e.g. [Applying UML and Patterns: An Introduction to Object-Oriented Analysis and Design and Iterative Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131489062) by Larman.

Comment: "We're sorry. The Web address you entered is not a functioning page on our site", so please can you explain more

Comment: It just an amazon link to the book.

Comment: If you want more information, you should do more research. I provided some starting points. Here another question on SO that should help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44909/what-essential-design-artifacts-do-you-produce